# When one node is very slow in Hadoop Cluster?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I've hadoop cluster of 5 nodes.

I've two concerns

1) What can be done when one of the node is running or processing data very slow (Not stopped) comapre to other nodes .. ?

2) I've set up log4j to capture logs, but How can I keep logs of all nodes at Name node or at one main server .. ?

Please suggest ...!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To question one, it's not clear which service is slow... Datanode? Namenode? Maybe you need to increase the heap sizes of these processes, or the Dataset you've stored is heavily skewed onto that server.

You would need to install monitoring software to capture IO, CPU, network, etc metrics to really diagnose any hardware bottlenecks. From there, make sure that that one server is running latest OS patches, has latest drivers, and a similar hardware profile of other machines you're comparing against. Maybe the hard drive or NIC is failing, but without hardware diagnostic software, it'd be hard to know

For question 2, you'd again need additional software, such as Elasticsearch, to centrally collect and index your logs from many systems

Comment: Its a Data node..! Which is running slow and all data nodes has same amount of data. If Data node gets failed, hadoop automatically takes care to put data on other node, but what about in slowness ..?

Comment: The amount of data doesn't matter. If lots of keys for a MapReduce job, for example, are stored on that node, then more mappers are required to read from there. In that case, it's not slow, just that more operations are being done on it... If you collected network traffic and plotted all nodes together, you might be able to observe that